# Can't see the pages in Word

Tags: ms-word

I was working on a document in Word. I accidentally pinched something and I can’t see the content anymore, I see only 1 empty lsit

I want to return back the contents of the sheet. Although all headings and word counts are preserved in the document

Comment: As long as you are not programming Word yourself, I would say this is the wrong place to ask :-)

Comment: So open the backup.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: This should be posted elsewhere, as pointed out in my previous comment. Before you do, though, try pressing Alt+F9 and see what happens. After observing that, press it again to return to normal viewing and post your question having that information.